# Can you explain what the 2nd caution on the LTAF VOR A chart means?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, vor, circling-approach, minimums

Can you explain what the 2nd caution on the LTAF VOR A chart means? "2. IF THE AIRCRAFT WILL MAKE A CIRCLING APPROACH VIA RIGHT TURN, ATC SHALL BE INFORMED AS SOON AS POSSIBLE." What exactly does this expression mean? I couldn't understand the use of "right turn" in particular. Because, although our main approach procedure is VOR A approach, is it meant to be described as a "Circling Approach" carried out from the north of the aerodrome? We see that the minimum value is also given as a circling, not a straight-in approach. Is this the 2nd caution written by considering VOR A approach as circling approach, or only the minimum value of VOR A approach is given as circling, and in fact, circling approach and VOR A approach are completely different things? I would appreciate it if you explain clearly by comparing the terms VOR A, circling approach, minimum value, and right turn. Here is the chart:
[image]

Comment: Have you asked any local pilots or ATC how this is expected to be flown?  Because I'm stumped why you would not be able to land straight ahead on a course of 228.  (although the base question about the warning is clear enough.)

Comment: @MichaelHall There is a question on that topic [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/95551/26229). There is a 591' obstacle just south of the extended certerline between the MAP and the runway threshold. This prevents a straight-in minimum from being published, but as far as I understand it doesn't prevent the pilot from landing straight-in if they have runway 23 in sight and can land safely.

Comment: I got the answer to this question where @Chris mentioned it as 591' height obstacle as stated. But the real problem here is how the VOR A and Circling procedures are separated or applied (right turn).

Comment: Ok, then I am unclear what you are asking.  The base question is asking about the meaning of #2, which as Chris points out is obvious.  And per this plate, *the VOR A **is** a circling approach.*  There are no straight in minimums, so what do you mean by how are they "*separated or applied*"?

Comment: I guess I couldn't express myself properly due to the language barrier. There are many questions that we need to understand before we can come to a conclusion here. If the approach we call VOR A is a circling approach, is the maneuver called "Right Turn" a maneuver that we will use when applying VOR A, or if the approach we call VOR A is a VOR approach, is the maneuver we call "Right Turn" a circling approach maneuver with a completely different procedure? First we have to decide. Theoretically or practically, is the VOR A approach straight or circling approach?

Comment: Is the "Right Turn" term to be used next, the turn maneuver we apply for the circling approach, independent of the VOR A approach when we perform to turn north of the aerodrome while descending at 228°? Or is it that we move away from the VOR, for example on the 060° course, so that the outbound is not 030° (i.e. not from the left of the approach line), that is, from the south of the aerodrome to the right, and we do this by assuming the main approach procedure, VOR A, as a circling?

Comment: @pilot162 You're overcomplicating things. A "right turn" is the basic maneuver that you learned on the first day of your PPL training, where you use the ailerons to bank the aircraft so that the right wing is lower than the left wing and the aircraft's course changes to the right.

Comment: This is where I think speaking with local pilots and ATC would be most helpful. I *think* that they cannot publish straight in minimums due to violating obstacle clearance rules. But perhaps as long as you are visual and call it a "circling" you're legal to fly and land straight ahead?

Comment: Yes, as you said, this is probably the most logical way. @Chris it's not about the right turn maneuver (of course I know what it means to turn right), it's what procedure we do that maneuver with. The question is whether we should apply the right turn when moving away from the VOR or when approaching the runway with 228°. I apologize if I have misunderstood and complicate matters unnecessarily due to the language I use.

Comment: @pilot162 You need to follow the depicted course to the missed approach point. At the missed approach point, you either initiate the missed approach or descend to the aerodrome for landing. Turning off course before the missed approach point is neither allowed nor safe.

Comment: So, if we are going to make a circling approach, at which DME or point should we do it at 1200 feet? So we have to turn to the north of the aerodrome with a right turn when we are on the 228° course, right?

Comment: For any procedural questions, here or with local pilots or ATC, you should specify the landing runway.

Comment: @pilot162 As long as you stay within protected airspace, don't go south of the aerodrome, and don't descend below MDA until you need to to make a normal descent for landing, you can fly it however you like. Note that the 228 course puts you on the upwind leg for 23- if you are landing 23 and the visibility is good enough, you can fly over the aerodrome then turn right crosswind and just fly basically a normal VFR pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It means plainly what it says. A right turn is when you turn to the right. If you are going to make a right turn, you need to tell ATC as soon as possible that you are planning to do that. Since you are not authorized to turn left (as that takes you south of the aerodrome), this means you must notify ATC if you are not going to land straight-in.

[Your related question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/95551/26229) asks why this has no straight-in minimums published. The reason is that there is an obstacle just south of the extended centerline in between the missed approach point and the runway threshold. This prevents straight-in minimums from being published. It does *not* prevent the pilot from flying straight-in if they have the runway in sight and have sufficient time to make a normal approach for landing.

In other words, this is an approach where they want you to approach runway 23 straight-in, but they can't promise you the obstacle protection that they would need to for a straight-in approach. So they give you circling minimums and ask you to land straight-in if you can.

Comment: I'm writing to make sure I understand correctly: The circling approach maneuver we call "Right Turn" is the maneuver we decided to make a circle to land while approaching runway 23 on the 228° course, and because it is prohibited in the south of the aerodrome, we turn right and turn to the north of the aerodrome, right? Because the maneuver in which we turn left and move away from the VOR on the 030° course might also mean the term "Right Turn" if they consider the approach type we call VOR A as a circling approach? (Because the minimum is given as a circling, not a straight-in approach)@Chris

Comment: @pilot162 A "right turn" is when you turn to the right. If you turn left, that's a "left turn." For instance, you could overfly the field and then turn right to make right traffic for 23. You have to tell ATC if you're going to do this. Or you can just land straight-in on the 228° course for runway 23 without turning at all. You don't need to tell ATC if you are doing this, implying it's what ATC is assuming you will do. In other words, this is technically a circling approach but it doesn't actually want you to turn unless you need to.

Comment: From the 228° course a left turn is prohibited since it takes you south of the aerodrome. A right turn is allowed but you need to inform ATC. But you can also land without turning at all. This would look a lot like a straight-in approach, but because of the obstacles it is legally a circling approach.

Comment: Your last comment you added to your answer was exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you. Also, I would like to ask, wouldn't it be possible procedurally if the minimum value of 1200 feet was given as the straight-in approach value (as the name) and the missed approach point was before the obstacle on the approach line exactly at 8 DME? Thus, since 1200 feet is the minimum, a straight-in approach could be applied if there is a runway view before the obstacle at this altitude and at 8DME. (The issue is just not giving the name straight-in approach.) @Chris